# Where BigDecimal "/" is defined?

Tags: ruby

I thought `'3.0'.to_d.div(2)` is same as `'3.0'.to_d / 2`, but the former return `1` while latter returns `1.5`.

I searched by `def /` in Bigdecimal's github repository, but I couldn't find it.

https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=def+%2F&type=Code

Where can I find the definition? And which method is a equivalent to `/` in Bigdecimal?

In `Float` there is a `fdiv` method. Is there similar one in `Bigdecimal`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in the source code of the `bigdecimal` library, in the repository you linked to. [On line 3403 of `ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c`](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/blob/master/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L3403), `BigDecimal#/` is bound to the function `BigDecimal_div`:

```
rb_define_method(rb_cBigDecimal, "/", BigDecimal_div, 1);
```

[This function looks like this](https://github.com/ruby/bigdecimal/blob/master/ext/bigdecimal/bigdecimal.c#L1321-L1347):

```
static VALUE
BigDecimal_div(VALUE self, VALUE r)
/* For c = self/r: with round operation */
{
    ENTER(5);
    Real *c=NULL, *res=NULL, *div = NULL;
    r = BigDecimal_divide(&c, &res, &div, self, r);
    if (!NIL_P(r)) return r; /* coerced by other */
    SAVE(c); SAVE(res); SAVE(div);
    /* a/b = c + r/b */
    /* c xxxxx
       r 00000yyyyy  ==> (y/b)*BASE >= HALF_BASE
     */
    /* Round */
    if (VpHasVal(div)) { /* frac[0] must be zero for NaN,INF,Zero */
    VpInternalRound(c, 0, c->frac[c->Prec-1], (BDIGIT)(VpBaseVal() * (BDIGIT_DBL)res->frac[0] / div->frac[0]));
    }
    return ToValue(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because BigDecimal#div takes a second argument, precision, which defaults to 1.

```
irb(main):017:0> '3.0'.to_d.div(2, 2)
=> 0.15e1
```

However, when / is defined on BigDecimal,

```
rb_define_method(rb_cBigDecimal, "/", BigDecimal_div, 1);
```

They used 1 for the # of arguments, rather than -1 which means "variable number of arguments". So BigDecimal#div thinks it takes one required argument and one optional argument, whereas BigDecimal#/ takes one required argument and the optional arg is ignored. Because the optional argument is ignored, it's not initialized correctly, it gets an empty int or 0.

This may be considered a bug. You should consider opening an issue with the ruby devs.